# Limiting fraction of association

Tags: acid-base

> Show that the limiting fraction of association of a base in water, as
>   the concentration of base approaches 0, is $$\alpha=\frac{10^7 K_b}{(1+10^7\times K_\mathrm{b})}.$$

I have tried this problem for a long time and have made little progress. Here is what I have tried:

We know that:

\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{b} &= \frac{\ce{[HB+]}\ce{[OH-]}}{\ce{[B]}}\tag{definition}\\
\ce{[HB+]} + \ce{[H+]} &= \ce{[OH-]} \tag{charge balance}\\
\ce{[H+][OH-]} &= 10^{-14} \tag{$K_\mathrm{w}$ at $\pu{25^o C}$}\\
\text{initial concentration of base added} &= \ce{[B]} + \ce{[HB+]} \tag{mass balance}
\end{align}

I know that the limiting fraction of association is 
$$\alpha = \frac{\ce{[HB+]}}{\text{initial concentration of base added}} = \frac{\ce{[OH-]}}{(\ce{[B]} + \ce{[HB+]})},$$ 
but I'm confused about how to proceed from here. I tried putting $\alpha$ in terms of $\ce{[OH-]}$ to get a cancellation, but that proved difficult. How do I proceed?

Comment: Please use `\ce{}` only for actual chemical content, please don't wrap whole mathematical statements into it. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Start from

$$K_\mathrm{b} = \frac{\ce{[HB+]}\ce{[OH-]}}{\ce{[B]}}$$

Define

$$\alpha = \frac{\ce{[HB+]}}{\ce{[B]} + \ce{[HB+]}} $$

or

$$\frac{\ce{[HB+]}}{\ce{[B]}}=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$

so that

$$K_\mathrm{b} = \frac{\alpha\ce{[OH-]}}{1-\alpha}$$

or

$$\alpha = \frac{K_\mathrm{b}}{K_\mathrm{b}+\ce{[OH-]}}$$

But in the limit of infinite dilution the concentration of $\ce{OH^-}$ is solely determined by the autodissociation of water (if the solution is pure unbuffered water) and

$$\ce{[OH-]} = \sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}}$$

so that

$$\alpha = \frac{K_\mathrm{b}}{K_\mathrm{b}+K_\mathrm{w}^{1/2}}$$

But at RTP $K_\mathrm{w}^{1/2}\approx 10^{-7}$ resulting in the final expression

$$\alpha = \frac{10^{7}K_\mathrm{b}}{10^{7}K_\mathrm{b}+1}$$

Comment: @andselisk none really, both are (small) oversights resulting during editing of the text.